# Add order within group and mark whether a row is the last in its group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in an SQL Server database on the following form, sorted according to `id`.

```
id     group
1      10
17     10
24     10
2      20
16     20
72     20
104    20
8      30
9      30
```

I would like to select every row grouped according to the row `group` and add the following information to this table: the order (as sorted) within the group and whether the row is the last row in the group. In other words, something similar to this:

```
id     group   order  last
1      10      1      0
17     10      2      0
24     10      3      1
2      20      1      0
16     20      2      0
72     20      3      0
104    20      4      1
8      30      1      0
9      30      2      1
```

I've tried fiddling around with `ROW_NUMBER`, but I'm not all that experienced with SQL Server and I can't get it to work. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
select id,[group],
       row_number()over(partition by [group] order by id) as [order],
       case when row_number()over(partition by [group] order by id desc) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as Last
From yourtable
```